# In plesk api how do I add a user to a database if I don't know the database id

Tags: php, xml, database, api, plesk

With help from Oleg Neumyvakin I have managed to use plesk api to create a database, but now I need to add a user to that database. I have worked out how to add a user to a database,but it requires knowing the id of the database, which I won't know in php. For instance the following request code creates the database

```
<packet>
<database>
<add-db>
   <webspace-id>$webspaceId</webspace-id>
   <name>$dbName</name>
   <type>mysql</type>
</add-db>
</database>
</packet>
```

And the following code creates a user and adds it to the database

```
<packet>
<database>
  <add-db-user>
      <db-id>26</db-id>
      <login>zebra</login>
      <password>zebra500</password>
   </add-db-user>
</database>
</packet>
```

You can see my problem. The second part uses the id of the database which is 26 to add the user, but I don't know the id without looking in plesk, and that defeats the object.

So how do I create the database and add the user at the same time?

Comment: This is not a good way to access databases from PHP. You will be completely dependent on Plesk, and believe me, you don't want to. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: I know how to create databases the normal way eg "CREATE DATABASE" but this way does not show up in plesk, and this is what my boss wants. Also it does not assign it to the correct domain. I usually use mysqli and not pdo btw. I may use pdo later, but not had time to learn it yet. Also once the database is created I will be using mysqli to create tables and do all operations.

Comment: Well, ok, Plesk it is... :-) I almost assume that the first request will return a response, containing the database id. Can't you use that?

Comment: I will see if that will work. Will give it a go

Comment: See: https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/api-rpc/reference/managing-databases/creating-databases.34407/#o34412

Comment: Yes I have been reading this. That is how I worked out how to add a user. When the database is created it does return OK 27, or whatever. The id is in an id tag <id>27</id> so I may be able to use preg match to get the id. Working on it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of PHP built-in XML parsers like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) or [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)

Comment: Actually after I answered my own question I found that Simplexml is the way to go. So I am giving you the tick even though I answered it with a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have the answer at last. Although I am not sure if it is the best answer. At the moment it is the only answer. If you can give me a better solution. I will of course tick yours instead. I am getting the id back with the preg match then stripping the id tag and using the id to create a user.

```
$request = <<<EOF
<packet>
<database>

<add-db>
   <webspace-id>$webspaceId</webspace-id>
   <name>$dbName</name>
   <type>mysql</type>
</add-db>

</database>
</packet>
EOF;

$response = $client->request($request); // Send query to Plesk host
echo $response; // show response

// This gets the id by using preg match
preg_match('/<id>(.*)<\/id>/',$response,$match);
$databaseId=$match[0];
echo '</br></br>match:'.($databaseId).'</br></br>';
// This strips the id tag
$answer=$match[0];
$search = array('<id>', '</id>');
$replace = array("","");
$id = str_replace($search, $replace, $answer);

$request = <<<EOF
<packet>
<database>

  <add-db-user>
      <db-id>$id</db-id>
      <login>bert</login>
      <password>bert500</password>
   </add-db-user>

</database>
</packet>
EOF;

'</br></br>'.$response = $client->request($request); // Send query to Plesk host
echo $response; // show response
```